# Unable to access mediaStreamTracks of local and remote participants

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I am unable to obtain the `mediaStreamTracks` for local and remote participants, even after the `roomState` changes to connected. However, I noticed that they become available after reconnecting. Please advice how I could access the `mediaStreamTracks` for both local and remote participants after connecting to the room.

To reproduce the bug try the following code in Room component of this [repo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react).

```
// Below function is from room component of this repo
import useRoomState from '../../hooks/useRoomState/useRoomState';
import useVideoContext from '../useVideoContext/useVideoContext';

export default function Room() {
const { room } = useVideoContext();
  const {
    room: { localParticipant },
  } = useVideoContext();
  const [participants, setParticipants] = useState(Array.from(room.participants.values()));
  const roomState = useRoomState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(roomState === 'connected'){
          localParticipant.tracks.forEach(track => {
          if (track.kind === 'data' ) {
                      return;
            }
          console.log(track.mediaStreamTrack)  // Getting undefined!!
          }

        participants.forEach(participant => {
            participant.tracks.forEach(track => {
                  if (track.kind === 'data') {
                      return;
                   }
                   console.log(track.mediaStreamTrack)  // Getting undefined!!
            }
       }
  }, [roomState]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you call `tracks` on a `Participant` object you don't actually get the `Track` objects. Instead you get an array of [`TrackPublication` objects](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.7.0/docs/TrackPublication.html). A `TrackPublication` represents a track that has been published to a room, however it is not the `Track` object (which has the reference to the `MediaStreamTrack` that you're looking for) and, for remote participants, a `RemoteTrack` object may not yet exist until the `localParticipant` has subscribed to the track.

To handle this, you need to check whether the `TrackPublication` has the track available and if it does, use it, if it doesn't, listen for the "subscribed" event.

For example, with the remote participants:

```js
participants.forEach(participant => {
  participant.tracks.forEach(trackPublication => {
    if (track.kind === 'data') {
      return;
    }
    if (trackPublication.track) {
      console.log(trackPublication.track.mediaStreamTrack);
    } else {
      trackPublication.on("subscribed", track => {
        console.log(track.mediaStreamTrack)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.